# cannot ssh into server

Tags: ssh, sshd

**[Resolved][Read the answer below]** somehow pinging the IP Address resulting in `Request timeout`, it means there's an issue in the connection, between client and server endpoints. Credits to [user68186](https://askubuntu.com/users/68186/user68186) for helping me tracing the issue, thanks a lot!

I just upgraded Ubuntu server, from 14.04 to 16.04.

`ssh` service is already started in the server.

After the upgrade I cannot connect to server via SSH.

I'm using a custom port, say it's `1234`

`sshd_config logLevel` already set to `DEBUG3`, the highest level.

I tried to check the `auth.log` file, but it didnt' catch anything.

already set this in `iptables` :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

executing `ssh -vvv` from client terminal displaying this message :

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 74: Applying options for target_server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.1.2.3 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.1.2.3 [192.1.2.3] port 1234.
debug1: connect to address 192.1.2.3 port 1234: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.1.2.3 port 1234: Operation timed out
```

executing `ssh localhost` from client terminal produces :

```
Password:
Last login: Wed Feb  5 00:34:54 2020 from 127.0.0.1
Agent pid 22321
Identity added: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

any clues?

Comment: already checked fail2ban jail banned IP list, and it's empty

Comment: ok thanks, I'm trying the `ssh` with `-vvv` options at the moment

Comment: ok, let me read it first

Comment: after executing `ufw status` I received this message `The program 'ufw' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt install ufw`, so I think allowing port `1234` from `ufw` won't help

Comment: ssh-server service is already started

Comment: `user68186` thanks for helping me on this, really appreciated, let's continue, who knows we're close enough to the correct answer :)

Comment: I have run the `ssh localhost ` command, my friend cannot ssh either, so there must be something wrong with server

Comment: just typed `firewalld` and got this message `The program 'firewalld' is currently not installed`

Comment: omg, you're absolutely right, pinging the IP Address resulting in request timeout! There must be something wrong with the connection

Comment: ok done. Nope, it's not a bad or loose cable, my other friend could not ping it either. I could post to this thread, it means I have a good internet connection :)

Comment: ok done, since this is a request timeout issue, it will be a different issue, currently we're submitting ticket to our VPS provider to find out why

Comment: it might still have relation with ubuntu, prior to upgrading ubuntu the version, we could ssh into server, both my friend and me

Comment: I will update this post once we found out the real root cause

Comment: I finally found the root cause, but since this thread is closed, I'll post the answer here. it appears the iptables configuration was reset in the upgrade process, at such `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT` was placed in the order after the incoming IP blocking rule, which its previous rule would block any incoming access to the server.
I fixed it by resetting the iptables and made correct configuration, after that the problem resolved, anyone could connect through ssh

Comment: Thank you, I will post the answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Resolved]** I finally found the root cause.

it appears the iptables configuration was reset in the upgrade process.

At such `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT` was placed in the order after the incoming IP blocking rule, which it would block any incoming access to the server.

I fixed it by resetting the iptables and made correct configuration, after that the problem resolved, anyone could connect through ssh.